# Counterexample for necessary condition of integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Can you give me an example of a non-negative function on $[0,1]$ that is NOT integrable, but $\lim_{t \to \infty} t \mu\{x : |f(x)| \geq t \} =0$?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to note that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty \mu \left ( \left \{ x : f(x) \geq t \right \} \right ) dt$?